# Error capl error 17-0098 while target is set

Tags: diagnostics, capl, canoe

im writing a capl test case and getting the following error when expecting  a test response
Error capl error 17-0098 , even thought i already defined target and request is send successfully its just the response that capl test seem to not catch while i made sure response is returned correctly

Comment: Show (at least) your code. Also check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score -2):

Error 17-0098 is because your Diagnostic request/response service or identifier is not define in CDD. 
you could ignore it, if system response to the request you sent. 
here is an example to get response without CDD

```
on diagRequest yourEcuName.*
{
  diagResponse this resp;
  this.GetPrimitiveData(dataDiag, elcount(dataDiag));
  write("Received diagResponse: 0x%x 0x%x 0x%x", dataDiag[0], dataDiag[1], dataDiag[2]);
  switch(dataDiag[0])
  {
    case 0x22: // modify this for other Diag Service
    write("Received diagResponse Service $22 Read data by identifier");
    break;
    default:
    break;
  }

}
```

Comment: Please, use answers only to answer the question; not for commenting or asking for more detailed information.

Comment: im new here and dont have enought reputation to post comment.hope this follow the rule.

Comment: @T.T., no, it does not follow the rule. Please read [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/214173/248627)